# Split Payment using Paypal payment option

Tags: paypal, payment

Our use case is:

The seller sells the product to our platform, the buyer buys with PayPal and payment needs to get split to seller and owner of platform using PayPal

Any idea how to achieve this? We have found ways but they are depreciated in PayPal. Any alternative to achieve using Paypal.

Please help us to find it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: how did you manage to solve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives to implementing this feature are: Stripe Connect and Braintree Marketplace. These products enable you to choose how you manage the risk give most of the supporting features for a platform payments.

These are paid services, and the cost may prohibit your app. Another alternative is implementing this logic yourself, where you will have to keep track of the sales, the percentages to take for each one for taxes, commissions, fees, and the ledger to ensure money is not lost.

Some open source solutions can help you with the in-house implementation, such as [QLedger](https://github.com/RealImage/QLedger). Other managed solutions offer pieces of this infrastructure as a service, such as [Decimals](http://decimals.app/) [disclaimer: I'm the founder of Decimals]

You need to make sure you are aware of the risks of your platform. You won't be able to get money already sent to the seller Paypal account on chargebacks/refund requests, and will have to pay for them yourself.